# Difference between get_full_name() and get_short_name() Django

Tags: python, django, models

I have a doubt. I am doing a AbstractBaseUser and the documentation of Django 1.6 say this about getting the email for identify the user, but I don't understand what is the difference about this two functions:

```
#Documentation Django 1.6

def get_full_name(self):
    # The user is identified by their email address
    return self.email

def get_short_name(self):
    # The user is identified by their email address
    return self.email
```

Anyone can explain me the difference please? Thanks.

Comment: There is clearly no difference - in this example, the short name and the full name are both just the email address (that doesn't always have to be the case). It would be helpful to post a link to the documentation you're referring to.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Here is the link https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is *not* quite what the documentation for django-1.6 says. Here is what the documentation reads:

> get_full_name()
>       Returns the first_name plus the last_name, with a space in between.
>
> get_short_name()
>       New in Django 1.5.
>       Returns the first_name.

Here is the [relevant documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.get_full_name)

It might be some project specific user definition overrides which are defined this way.

Comment: Sorry, I was in the Development trunk. Thanks for your answer.